# Balabolka Text to Speech Substitute "Web Links" Pronounciation

Tags: text-to-speech, balabolka

The program reads out the entire web address

for example it pronounces the ENTIRETY of "http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/0ac15d76-1491-404a-9bd8-a8401dac0078/"

that's pretty annoying.

I want it to read web addresses as "X dot com weblink" or just "web link" similar to the program Textaloud. Is there a way to get Balabolka to make this substitution?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. It allows wildcards with * symbol

Can put before and after eg. *abc*  abc*   *abc

Comment: oops, nevermind. that is only a step in the right direction. Want to read the entire long web address as "web link"

Answer (score 0):

Balabolka supports Regular Expressions in Search and Replace.  You could do this:

Search for http/https URLs (save domain in $1): `%rex%https?://([^ \t/$.?#][^/ \t]+)[^ \t]*`.
Replace with `$1 web link` to obtain "foo.com web link", or just with `web link`.

Use with care.

This would be easier in a decent text editor though: you'd have better regex, and redo support!